# Removing Space between bars in seaborn barplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot following data. Duration is Jan to Dec. Type varies from 1 to 7. Key point is, not all types exist for each month. This is not missing value, type simply do not exist.

```
Month  Type  Coef
Jan      1    2.3
Jan      2    2.1
..
```

Code:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Month', y = 'Coef_E',hue = 'LCZ',data = df_E, palette=palette)
```

Result

[image]

I want to remove space market by arrows.

Comment: It's hardly possible with seaborn. You can manually position the bars where you want them to appear as shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) (where you would need to customize `ind` to your needs).